# How to get the data from oracle on the following demand？

Tags: oracle

**The table like this.**

bh         sl    productdate

a1         100    2022-1-1

a1         220    2022-1-2

a1         220    2022-1-3

a2         200    2022-1-1

a2         350    2022-1-2

a2         350    2022-1-3

**The result like this.**

bh   sl_q(sl_before) sl_h(sl_after) sl_b(changeValue) productdate

a1        100              220           120         2022-1-2

a2        200              350           150         2022-1-2

Rules:the same field bh, when  the field sl change,then get the record.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a `ROW_NUMBER` trick here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY bh ORDER BY productdate) rn1,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY bh ORDER BY productdate DESC) rn2
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT bh, MAX(CASE WHEN rn1 = 1 THEN sl END) AS sl_q,
           MAX(CASE WHEN rn2 = 1 THEN sl END) AS sl_h,
           MAX(CASE WHEN rn2 = 1 THEN sl END) - 
               MAX(CASE WHEN rn1 = 1 THEN sl END) AS sl_b
FROM cte
GROUP BY bh;
```

Comment: There are more records, the field sl may change many times ,then need get the records at each time

Comment: You should ask a new question.  This one has already been answered.